Job (or other mechanism) to trigger multiple other jobs (in the same pipeline) in GitLab CI?
We have a setup where we have many manual jobs to deploy to multiple environments, and 90% of the time, we only manually click and deploy one or two. But sometimes, we need to deploy all, and then we have to click a gazillion manual buttons. Any way to have a job that itself triggers other, otherwise manually triggered jobs ?

should this job be available all the time and also be a manual job?

Yes to both questions

There are some solutions for this.

In the latest versions, If you add all these manual job in one stage, there will be a button on top of the jobs saying "Run all manual" that will run all of them.


you can generate the pipeline by a script, and have the two options on "run all" or "run one by one". Example:


gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
  - generate
  - run

generate-config:
  stage: generate
  script:
    - ./generate-configs.sh
    - cat config-manual.yml
    - cat config-auto.yml
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - config-manual.yml
      - config-auto.yml

trigger-manual:
  stage: run
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: config-manual.yml
        job: generate-config

trigger-auto:
  stage: run
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: config-auto.yml
        job: generate-config

generate-configs.sh
#!/bin/bash

cat > config-manual.yml <<EOF
job-manual-1:
  script:
    - echo 'job 1 for manual'
job-manual-2:
  when: manual
  script:
    - echo 'job 2 for manual'
  when: manual
EOF

cat > config-auto.yml <<EOF
job-auto-1:
  script:
    - echo 'job 1 for auto'
job-auto-2:
  script:
    - echo 'job 2 for auto'
EOF


I'm not at work to try that out, though from what I understand it seems like it might be a solution. A few questions: are the cat commands only for debugging, or do they serve another purpose ? And is the mismatch of config-a.yml / config-auto.yml a typo or is there more to it ?

yes, cat is for just showing the a command. the other one is fixed.
